# How can i make a left hand in blender a right hand

Tags: modeling

I made and rigged a hand model, but it is a left hand, i need left and right, how could i make the left hand a right hand?

Comment: As Ryou says you can mirror your hand (Ctrl + M + axis, or S + axis + -1), once mirrored select all in Edit mode and Shift N to recalculate the normals of the mirrored object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me if I misunderstood your question but perhaps you can:

1. Make a copy of the left hand. (Shift + D)
2. Right click the copy of left hand.
3. Mirror - (Choose appropriate axis).

Comment: this sort of worked, how do i remove the original hand and just keep the mirror?

Comment: You can just delete the original hand by selecting it, pressing "x" (shortcut to delete object) and choosing delete.
or better yet, skip step number 1 and just mirror the original object.